# Query function to pull data based on multiple values within one cell

Tags: google-sheets-api

I would like to ask how to use Query function where one of the cell contains multiple comma separated values

For example:-

To pull col2 values when Col 1 is B, it would be straightforward.

| Col 1 | Col 2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| D | 4 |

```
=QUERY(A1:B3,"select B where A = '"&D3&"' ",0)

D3 cell value is B
```

Similar to how we have IN clause in SQL, I would like to pull data from col 2 when col1 values are B,C,D.

Would it be possible to concatenate the results in one row as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

`=join(", ", QUERY(A1:B4,"select B where "&CONCATENATE("A = '", join("' or A = '", SPLIT(D4, ",")), "'"),0))`

Where `D4` = `B,C,D`

#### Sample Output:

[image: Sample]

#### Note:

- The values on column B below are the value of the formula:

`CONCATENATE("A = '", join("' or A = '", SPLIT(D4, ",")), "'"),0))`

Since there was no `in` statement in sheets query (not that I have encountered), what I did was split those said values in column `D` and have them format like the multiple `or` statements which are equal to a single `in` statement. This is a workaround and should do what you wish to achieve.

Comment: Excellent stuff!! Thank you so much NaziA. God bless