# Regular expression with and logic in Query formula select statement jielding no hit

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to do a fuzzy search and find appropriate match for a list of 450 merchandise whose names have been changed (order of words changed, capitalization changed, some new words added) with query formula in google sheets.

I've been trying with vlookup but it does not take (interpret - exectute properly) the regular expressions :(

After days of research I managed to compose a formula that parses and runs withouth error messages but unfortunately doesn't give desired result :(

Formula is like this:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tWyHmkm2YAIXpzgs4A0KEFJ5XJhAT61yL_ZuqHtys6g/edit#gid=272207476", "Sheet1!A1:A447"), "select * where Col1 matches ' (?=.*\b"&IFERROR(PROPER(INDEX(SPLIT(A1, " "),1))," ")&"\b) (?=.*\b"&IFERROR(PROPER(INDEX(SPLIT(A1, " "),2))," ")&"\b) (?=.*\b"&IFERROR(PROPER(INDEX(SPLIT(A1, " "),3))," ")&"\b) ' Limit 1" ,0)
```

Value in cell A1 that should be taken as a search basis (search-key) is "Ajwain whole 1Kg       "

And the result (match) should be "Spice Ajwain Seeds Whole 1Kg"

Above stated query formula throws N/A error as if no match is found although the desired result (match) is contained in spreadsheet from which the range to search in is imported by importrange formula.

I tested Importrange formula and imports nicely what is expected.

It looks like the culprit is the regular expression search criteria :(

I just cannot see why it does not find the desired result while it is there in the range to search in :(

I tried also getting help from ChatGPT but it didn't give any usefull hint except that everything looks ok.

Spreadsheet with the list of modified merchandise names is given as a link to it in above given query formula in its importarange part: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tWyHmkm2YAIXpzgs4A0KEFJ5XJhAT61yL_ZuqHtys6g/edit#gid=272207476

Spreadsheet to test the above given query formula is on this link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1opH7qmXoDC41hg3eapUEpFoyM_KZ9o42nznczB3QFe8/edit?usp=sharing

Obviously I don't see something :( Any suggestions please?

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & work out a solution. You may also use the [anonymous blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by docs community forum for ease of sharing.

Comment: realistic input data and expected result - output - manually entered as well as the link to the spreadsheet with the list in which to search for a match is given from the very first publishing of the problem in first and second paragraph below the stated query formula in the description of the problem.
realistic input is:"Ajwain whole 1Kg  "
expected output (match) is:"Spice Ajwain Seeds Whole 1Kg"
link to the spreadseet with the list in which to search for match is:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tWyHmkm2YAIXpzgs4A0KEFJ5XJhAT61yL_ZuqHtys6g/edit#gid=272207476
Thanks.

Comment: Your ideal expected output item `Spice Ajwain Seeds Whole 1Kg` is not present/available in the *article_list* sheet?

Comment: Yes :( You are right :( Great blunder from me :( Thanks for finding and pointing it out.

Comment: I've been bussy with some other projects for a while and only now got some time to add my ideal expected output into the search list and test my formula but still not getting any hit (match) :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this in cell B1 of "TestingFuzzySearch", where cell A1 is the search term:

`=query({IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tWyHmkm2YAIXpzgs4A0KEFJ5XJhAT61yL_ZuqHtys6g/edit#gid=272207476", "Sheet1!A1:A447")},"select Col1 where Col1 is not null and "&CONCATENATE("lower(Col1) contains '", join("' and lower(Col1) contains '", SPLIT(lower(A1), " ")), "'"))`

---

The key is: `CONCATENATE("lower(Col1) contains '", join("' and lower(Col1) contains '", SPLIT(lower(G1), " ")), "'")`

- returns: "lower(Col1) contains 'ajwain' and lower(Col1) contains 'whole' and lower(Col1) contains '1kg'"
- lower(Col1) is necessary since the search terms can be uncapitalized; such as "whole" Vs "Whole"
- lower(A1) - the search terms *may* be capitalised, so the reference values need to be rendered in lower case. For example: "Ajwain" => "ajwain"; "Whole" => "whole"

---

h/t @NightEye
[Query function to pull data based on multiple values within one cell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66587101/1330560)